# check if user exists with php and mysql stmt

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm creating an authentification file with php and mysql, but I have this mistake in this line:

```
$stmt2->bind_param('ss',$twitter_id, $name);
```

The error message is

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ...

Where's my mistake?

- $name in my database is a `VARCHAR`
- $twitter_id in my database is a `VARCHAR`
- $bd is my database connection

If a user is already registered, it should show me a message saying "User already registered", and if the user isn't registered, it should insert a new id and name in my database.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['userdata'])) {
    header("location: index.php");
} else {
    $userdata = $_SESSION['userdata'];
    $name = $userdata->name;
    $twitter_id = $userdata->id;
    $stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT ID_TWITTER FROM USERS");
    $stmt->execute();                
    $stmt->bind_result($checkUser);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if($checkUser!==$twitter_id){
            $cSQL = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID_TWITTER, FULL_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            $stmt2 = $bd->prepare($cSQL);
            $stmt2->bind_param('ss',$twitter_id, $name);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->close();
    } else {
        echo "User already exits";
    }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Can you compare your column names with the one's in the db/table? Could be a typo issue I believe.

Comment: yeah, I already checked it, it's with the same names

Comment: bind_param send 2 parametres to VALUES $stmt2->bind_param('ss',$twitter_id, $name);

Comment: Add this line in your code  - 
echo ini_get('display_errors'); and see what errors are you getting..

Comment: thanks, I already tried it but it show me the same error message Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved : it works now

```
        $stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT ID_PROVIDER FROM USERS WHERE ID_PROVIDER = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $twitter_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($checkUser);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $result = $checkUser;
        }
        if (empty($result)) {
            $cSQL = "INSERT INTO USERS (ID_TWITTER, FULL_NAME) 
           VALUES(?,?)";
            $stmt2 = $bd->prepare($cSQL);
            $stmt2->bind_param('ss', $twitter_id, $name);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->close();
        }else {
    echo "User already exits";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: I do this exact thing in [a project I have on github](https://github.com/HirotoKun/admin-panel/blob/master/admin/private.php). Feel free to use the classes for whatever you like; they are mostly copy-pastable.

Your *real* issue is that [`$bd->prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returned false.
Check that you actually called it correctly and set it to `new mysqli(*params)`

The error `Call to a member function ... on a non-object in ...` means that `$db` is not an object, which means that it was not instantiated to an object. Thus, `$this->method()` isn't possible. `bind_param(string $format, mixed &*vars);` uses pass-by-reference and if this fails, it throws an error.
Try it yourself by sticking this in there:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", "string", "string");
```

To get around this issue where it can fail, check if `$db->prepare()` returns true:

```
if ($query = $bd->prepare($sql)) {
    //stuff
}
```

In addition, in the first query you do it is probably not a good idea to be adding the overhead of a prepare for a single query that only checks row count without user input.

Comment: are you getting the same error message? because that error message comes from calling a class function on something that isnt a class.

Comment: also, when not inserting user input and simply fetching a row, using a simple `$bd->query()` can save you a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a typo? does $bd exist or should it be $db ?

Comment: I had the feeling it might have been that (check the revision history on my answer), but i was giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.